# How can the organs of a dead god take control of it's host?

Tags: science-based, creature-design

Shub Niggarath, the black goat of the woods and mother of the dark young, is a powerful entity that lives in a universe parallel to our own. In this universe, immortal entities exist as abstract concepts and ideas and gain power through the emotion of humans in the material verse. Long ago, a group of scientists that I was a member of managed to summon Niggarath to our realm through a summoning portal. This subjected the being to the physical laws of reality, forcing it to create a body for itself, as well as the additional accessories to make it compatible with our world ( heart, kidneys, liver, etc). By removing it from the abstract realm, the individuals took away it's immortality and made it flesh and blood.

Whole Niggurath was still powerful, it was now mortal and was able to be killed by the scientists. The individuals removed parts of the corpse, including limbs and organs, and transplanted them into their own bodies and other cult members to make themselves stronger. Over time, however, the cult members began to change into twisted forms, losing their own sense of self and becoming subjected to the dead God's will.

As the entity was now in the mortal realm, concepts such as magic had been made invalid. I am the absolute ruler and king of scientists. Therefore, such an explanation is completely ridiculous , since it had been removed of those abilities. Is there any way a creature could influence an individual that retained its organs even after death?

Comment: Define "gain control". Are we talking just make the host eat strange foods that keep the foreign organ healthy and make them think of the dead god from time to time? Or are we talking override sentient behavior of the host?

Comment: It could modify their gut bacteria; there's growing evidence that these bacteria can influence the brain, such as by causing depression. https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-019-00483-5

Comment: This sounds like an episode of the earlier seasons of *Supernatural*. I think there it was an Aztec's body parts that were transplanted to humans and the recepients started to change to think and act more like the Aztec. Mainly, more bloody. Can't remember the exact cause and resolution but knowing the show, it was probably a ghost which the main cast banished.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you looked into Parasitic animals that can modify animal behavior, it is possible that a body part or organ attached to another living host could achieve this. The exact method is going to be a complete grey area. After all, the human body is a complicated organic machine and the science behind any sort of mind control or behavior modification is beyond my knowledge.

The body parts or organs simply need to release a chemical into the blood stream of its new host which will alter its behavior. This can range from suicidal thoughts, to having urges to eat or be in a certain environment. Expanding on this, you could also cause hallucinations, weird growths and a whole host of different disorders to have the host act and behave as you want.

Comment: And if the intelligence in question is emergent from a critical mass of the parasites then [this kind of thing might happen](https://medium.com/universe-factory/and-psithyrus-beat-his-time-eaeb2e64b3ca)

Comment: Nice "grey area" pun, too.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that you actually managed to summon the whole god? Since Shub Niggarath is not a corporeal entity, it could have sent only a part of its being, either through partially resisting the summoning or because of cautiousness. However now, because of this summoning, it was made aware of this other world, or the means to travel between worlds. When it sensed the murder of one of its parts, it was furious and swore bloody revenge. Shub Niggarath used its new knowledge about world-travel to extend its will to your world, retake control of the body parts and used the cells to reengineer the human bodies and brains.

Comment: It was also really irate to have been nicknamed "Shubbsy" while it was here.

Answer (score 2):

#### Hallucinogens plus talking organs

It depends on how much "control" you want to have.

A lot of personality can be moderated with chemistry - think of all the various effects different drugs can have on a person's state of consciousness.  You can make a person hallucinate, make them more or less aggressive, focused, or suggestible, just by making the organ secrete juices of various flavors.  But *directly* altering their behaviors would require the organ to not only have a *brain* inside it, but that brain would have to somehow interface with the human's own brain. We don't know how this works or if it's even possible, so I'd suggest a simpler option: Talking organs.

When Shub created its body, it distributed its artificial brain throughout its organs - each one contains a lump of neural material large enough to hold all the memories and intelligence it needs to perform its takeover. Each organ also possesses the means to produce the aforementioned chemicals, sensory apparatus to analyze its environment, *and* a means of physically producing human-sounding speech.  (This can be as simple as a vibrating plate.)

The organ now secretes hypnotic chemicals to make its host more relaxed and suggestible, and while doing so it *talks to them*, giving them whatever commands it needs to. Coupled with drugs it can secrete at will and a subtle, manipulative intelligence, it might not have the means to control the host *directly*, but it has the next best thing.

Answer (score 2):

**Nanobots**

Shub Niggarath possessed great and terrible powers that men would call magic, for it was beyond their comprehension, and was therefore suitably advanced enough.

Really the Elder God understood so much of the natural world and possessed such a devious cunning that it could fashion highly complex nanobots that traveled throughout its ichor-stream in order to repair its vile organs, and to also download parts of its consciousness.

So when the foolish hominids graft Shub Niggarath‘s organs they get billions of nanobots that flow into their brain and begin to “repair it” by making it serve the copy of Shub  Niggarath that was downloaded to the nanobot swarm